# Adjust Privileges SE_DEBUG_NAME

Tags: c, winapi

I'm trying to make a WriteProcessMemory program, but I need to adjust my privileges to successfully open the Process' Memory.
But i have no idea how. I googled few hours and found a piece of code, but I'm still stuck. 
The Code which i found on the internet :

```
BOOL isOK;
HANDLE hToken;
HANDLE hCurrentProcess;
hCurrentProcess = GetCurrentProcess(); // 1
isOK = OpenProcessToken( hCurrentProcess, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken );
SetPrivilege( hToken, SE_DEBUG_NAME, TRUE );
```

the "SetPrivilege" is bringing the "Error C3861: "SetPrivilege": Identifier not found"
How am i supposed to enable the SE_DEBUG_NAME privilege? 
Any help is welcome!

Comment: Most likely the example you found is referring to a function that the author defined, which is why the compiler doesn't know what that symbol means.  MSDN doesn't mention a SetPrivilege function.

Answer (score 5):

That function is not a Win32 API function. Most likely it is this function from the MSDN example found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446619.aspx

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "cmcfg32.lib")

BOOL SetPrivilege(
    HANDLE hToken,          // access token handle
    LPCTSTR lpszPrivilege,  // name of privilege to enable/disable
    BOOL bEnablePrivilege   // to enable or disable privilege
    ) 
{
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
    LUID luid;

    if ( !LookupPrivilegeValue( 
            NULL,            // lookup privilege on local system
            lpszPrivilege,   // privilege to lookup 
            &luid ) )        // receives LUID of privilege
    {
        printf("LookupPrivilegeValue error: %u\n", GetLastError() ); 
        return FALSE; 
    }

    tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
    if (bEnablePrivilege)
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
    else
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = 0;

    // Enable the privilege or disable all privileges.

    if ( !AdjustTokenPrivileges(
           hToken, 
           FALSE, 
           &tp, 
           sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES), 
           (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES) NULL, 
           (PDWORD) NULL) )
    { 
          printf("AdjustTokenPrivileges error: %u\n", GetLastError() ); 
          return FALSE; 
    } 

    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED)

    {
          printf("The token does not have the specified privilege. \n");
          return FALSE;
    } 

    return TRUE;
}
```

I cannot be sure that this function is the same as that used by the author of the code sample you are using. I suggest you re-read that code sample and see if you can find the missing link.